# printing strings doubles and integers from a different file

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner, token, java-io

So I'm new to java and I have to read strings, doubles, and integers from a file and print them out after. This is the error that java is throwing at me:

> error: variable declaration not allowed here Scanner file = new
>   Scanner(line);

what am does it mean?

Comment: is your logic written inside main method? Post complete program.

Comment: It has been a while since I've java'd, but it looks like you're using the variable `line` in your `if(!line.equals(""))` before it is declared.

Comment: It means it might be allowed somewhere else, so where do you have this line? More context, please.

Comment: @veefu: No, that would be 'cannot find symbol: line`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(line);
```

Fails because a variable named file is already declared above ...

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(data);
```

Give one of the scanner variables a different name.  There's some other problems with your code, but I assume this is a school assignment so only answered the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] splited = line.split(" ");
            for (String st: splited) {

                if(isInteger(st))
                    System.out.println("---int--->"+st);
                else  if(isDouble(st))
                    System.out.println("---dubl--->"+st);
                else if (!st.isEmpty())
                    System.out.println("---String--->"+st);




            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

    }

   private static boolean isInteger(String st) {
      try {
         Integer.parseInt(st);
         return true;
       } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
     }
   }

   static boolean isDouble(String str) {
      try {
         Float.parseFloat(str);
         return true;
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          return false;
      }
    }


   This Maybe help you
```